# Powerbank instead of Alkaline D batteries

Tags: batteries, powerbanks

I am an avid fan of charcoal bbq and love fire starters/blowers like [these](https://www.amazon.ae/gp/product/B07RHTVYDV/).

They require type D 1.5 V alkaline batteries which are increasingly harder to get and  usually run out in the most inconvenient moment.

Instead of buying a bunch of these batteries I was wondering if I could use a simple 5V power bank with some module to get it down to 1.5 and power up the blower, ideally without soldering.

Comment: You can just run it at 5v it will just blow really hard.

Comment: @user3528438  I don't think the motor will like that for prolonged periods of time.

Comment: How many D batteries?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that yes, you can. There's plenty of cheap step-down modules available on amazon, ebay etc, and while I'm certainly not a fan of their build quality, they might sure get the job done here. Make sure to not get one with a low current rating; I'm pretty sure the motor will draw more than 2 A.

The question whether you can do it without soldering: huh, possible, but unlikely, you still need to solve the whole electro-mechanical problem of how to connect things to the former 1.5 V battery contacts of your blower.